# C# Find poke button on Facebook via broswer

Tags: c#, html, facebook, performance

I want to make a fb auto poker and currently have a code by searching for tagname of "div" and then for each item in htmlelementcollection I search for "a", then finally use the innertext to see if it is "poke back" or not. The problem is that that piece of code runs on a timer that ticks 10 times per second and it takes up to 20% cpu and 125 mb of memory. Is there a faster way I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't a while(true) { do... sleep(10000); } be more efficient way to have a never ending loop.

Comment: Oh I wanted to have the option to "stop" poking and then "start" poking and also without lagging the form itself

Comment: Use a separate thread for the loop and start/stop this thread. I guess you need polling (even when using selenium or something to control the browser, there's a polling with a sleep) but ever second or even less should be enough.